# How to get flexbox columns to be the same height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to wrap my head around flexbox and I have hit a wall with something very simple that I can't seem to get right.

I have 6 columns that I want all the same height with 3 on each row. I have set the flex items to have a width of 33% but I have not set a height on anything. I thought once the flex items had content it would take the one with the greatest height and match everything to it.

Here is my markup:

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.row-flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.icon-box-1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-flex">
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          One
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Two
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Three
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Four
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Five
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Six
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equal height columns feature comes from `align-items: stretch`, which is an initial setting on a flex container. It makes flex items consume all available space in the *cross axis*.

If you check the actual size of each flex item, you will see that they are, in fact, equal height on each row ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x7a37s7d/)).

The problem is that the content of each item (`.icon-box-1`) is not stretching full height. It's just `height: auto` (content height), by default.

In order for the content to stretch full height, add `display: flex` to each flex item, so `align-items: stretch` goes into effect, like on the parent ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x7a37s7d/1/)).

Then use `flex: 1` to make the content fill the remaining space on the *main axis* ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x7a37s7d/2/)).

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.row-flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 1px dashed red; /* for illustration */
  display: flex; /* new */
}

.icon-box-1 {
  flex: 1; /* NEW */
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-flex">
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          One
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Two
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Three
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Four
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Five
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Six
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great thank you so much for your help with this

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "display: flex" to .flexbox and "flex: 0 1 auto" to the icon box so it fills the heights out. Here ya go:

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.row-flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icon-box-1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-flex">
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          One
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Two
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Three
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Four
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Five
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="icon-box-1">
        <h1>
          Six
        </h1>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>lots of random text, lots of random text, lots of random text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```